# How to remove permanently a path from the fish $PATH?

Tags: linux, shell, fish

This question has already been asked, and answered here: https://superuser.com/a/940041/293429

However, the provided solution: executing `set -e PATH[<index-of-the-path-to-be-removed]` only applies to the running instance and is not valid universally.

After executing that command, if one executes `echo $PATH` the previously removed paths will occur again.

One way to completely reset the path is to execute: `set -U fish_user_paths`, but it is unclear to me that what it does.

The real trick would be to find out how to remove a path which has been manually added and make it available globally -- not only for the current instance?

Comment: See http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_path for some information. setting the universal variable `fish_user_paths` will rebuild the PATH variable in all yourfish sessions.

Comment: @charles, nope, that's not the fish config file. They live in ~/.config/fish

Comment: " One way to completely reset the path is to execute: set -U fish_user_paths, but it is unclear to me that what it does."  it cleared up a lot of garbage for me. I decided to set it at the beginning of my config.fish as a result. works well :) thanks for the question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's two ways to do this, and which one is valid depends on how the path got into $PATH.

It is possible to add directories to $PATH via e.g. `set PATH $PATH /some/dir`. At least by default, PATH is a global variable, which means it is per-session. That means to change something from $PATH, either remove it from where it is added (which is likely outside of fish since it inherits it), or put the `set -e` call in your ~/.config/fish/config.fish so it will be executed on every start.

There is also $fish_user_paths, which is a universal variable (meaning it carries the same value across fish sessions and is synchronized across them). On startup and whenever fish_user_paths is modified, fish adds it to $PATH. If the offending directory is added here, execute `set -e fish_user_paths[index]` once (e.g. in an interactive session).

`set -e fish_user_paths` would remove the entire variable (while `set -U fish_user_paths` would clear it) which would also work but would also remove all other paths

Comment: `set -e fish_user_paths[index]` fits bets my case. Thanks @faho

Comment: Note: `index` starts at 1.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @faho's answer, the following function may be useful to whoever reads this:

```
function fish_rm_path --argument path
    set path (path resolve $path)
    set path_index (contains -i $path $fish_user_paths)

    if test $status -ne 0
        echo $path not in fish_user_paths
        return 1
    end

    echo Removing $path at index $path_index from fish_user_paths

    set -e fish_user_paths[$path_index]
end
```

PS: be aware that the function doesn't check if the path is in `fish_user_paths` multiple times, and only removes the first instance it finds